# PowerBi Circular Dependancy issue

Tags: powerbi, circular-dependency

I have a case where I'm getting a circular dependency.

I'm trying to calculate what stock will arrive to our warehouse by a certain date, but the eta_date is a calculated date column.

The formula reporting the problem is this :

```
SIT Arriving Soon = 
VAR PastDate = Today() - 40
VAR FutureDate = TODAY() + 14

return
CALCULATE(SUMX(OnOrder,OnOrder[Open ASN qty [units]]]), DATESBETWEEN(OnOrder[ETA Date],PastDate, FutureDate)
)
```

The issue is that the datesbetween function needs a column to refer to, and my column is the calculated column below, which only refers to other columns within the 'onorder' table:

to understand this formula, here is a small key:
InT is a true/false if a quantity is in transit
Open ASN qty = the qty that is in transit
I then look at different vendors and the shipping mode used to add the number of days transport time.
I then do a calculation to add to the transport time to the 'invoiced by supplier' date, and if the vendor is not one of the defined vendors, then we use the default calculated date "OnOrder[Target VSL3 Date]"

```
ETA Date = 
Var InT = if ( OnOrder[Open ASN qty [units]]] <> 0, 1,0)
Var AAVend = if(  OnOrder[Vendor] = "451633" ||
                  OnOrder[Vendor] = "97051583"|| 
                  OnOrder[Vendor] = "452825", "AA", "Non-AA")
Var AATransTime = if( AAVend = "AA", IF(OnOrder[Ship Mode] = "Blitz", 5, IF(OnOrder[Ship Mode] =       "Air", 14, 42)), 500)
var TransTime = IF(AATransTime > 0, AATransTime, 99999)
RETURN
if ( InT = 1, DATEADD(OnOrder[Ship Date].[Date], TransTime,DAY), OnOrder[Target VSL3 Date].    [Date])
```

Can anyone help me to get this issue sorted, or advise a way on how I could calculate this?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the DATESBETWEEN and just filter on the date column:

```
SIT Arriving Soon = 
VAR PastDate = Today() - 40
VAR FutureDate = TODAY() + 14

return
CALCULATE(SUM(OnOrder[Open ASN qty [units]]]), OnOrder[ETA Date] >= PastDate && OnOrder[ETA Date] <=FutureDate)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply. I tried the formula, and I still get the circular reference error. It talks about the field 'ADC invoice number'. Here is the code to that :

```
ADC Invoice No = 
CALCULATE ( FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'ADC Movements'[ADC Invoice Number], 1 ), FILTER ( ALL (     'ADC Movements' ), 'ADC Movements'[PoFull] = OnOrder[PoFull] ) )
```

I don't see how this conflicts at all.